# Mailmerge from Visual Studio connection to SQL database with vb.net System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Command failed'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, mailmerge

I'm trying to connect directly to an SQL server for a mail-merge from a word template so that I can create letters with the letter based on an sql statement (example below) however I get this error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Command failed'

Yet the template, and the connection string seem correct.

```vb
Dim oWord As Word.Application = New Word.Application

Dim oDoc As Word.Document = oWord.Documents.Add("C:\Desktop\VATRATES.dotx")

oDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(Name:="", Connection:="Driver = {Sql Server};Data Source=CORRECT_IP_ADDRESS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CSJ;User ID=MYUSERNAME;Password=MYPASSWORD;", SQLStatement:="Select * from VATRATES")

oDoc.MailMerge.Execute(True) oDoc.SaveAs(SaveFileName)
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but any assistance is greatly appreciated

Comment: If you check the SQL Server Express instance's ERRORLOG do you see any `Error 18456` events? Take note of the `State` number there and compare it against the `State` numbers listed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to see what the issue is. Of course it may be something entirely not-login-related.

Comment: Thanks, as far as I can see there is nothing wrong with the SQL login in the log. So it doesn't even look like it's finding the connection.. I'm not sure if there is something i need to ensure is enables to do this in this way, as I've got other things like datagridviews, dropdowns etc and updates going to/from the sql server fine i just can't seem to get this to work.